# ServiceStack custom route variable placeholder doesn't have any constraint validation?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have 2 endpoints built by ServiceStack services:

- `DELETE: /parents/{parentId}` to delete a parent, along with all its children
- `DELETE: /parents/{parentId}/children/{childId}` to delete a child for the selected parent

#### Delete parent: /parents/{parentId}

```cs
[Api("Delete a parent")]
[Tag("Parent")]
[Route("/parents/{parentId}", HttpMethods.Delete)]
public class DeleteParentRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    [ApiMember(ParameterType = "path", IsRequired = true)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

[Authenticate]
public class ParentService : Service
{
    ...

    public void Delete(DeleteParentRequest request)
    {
        // Logic to delete parent, along with all its children
    }
}
```

#### Delete Parent Child: /parents/{parentId}/children/{childId}

```cs
[Api("Delete a parent child")]
[Tag("Parent Child")]
[Route("/parents/{parentId}/children/{childId}", HttpMethods.Delete)]
public class DeleteParentChildRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    [ApiMember(ParamterType = "path", IsRequired = true)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(ParameterType = "path", IsRequired = true)]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}

[Authenticate]
public class ParentChildService : Service
{
    ...

    public void Delete(DeleteParentChildRequest request)
    {
        // Delete the parent child
    }
}
```

These 2 endpoints are working as expected.

Unfortunately (or actually fortunately), our QA passed the wrong endpoint when testing the delete child endpoint. What he put on Postman was `DELETE: /parents/children?parentId=1&other=rndString`.

What I expect when we call that wrong endpoint is that we should get a 404 not found, since it doesn't match with any of our endpoints. But surprisingly, it actually called the delete-parent endpoint `DELETE: /parents/{parentId}`.

How would that happen, even I already have a matching **integer** property called `ParentId` in the request DTO that tells ServiceStack that I am expecting an integer from the route? Does ServiceStack have its own routing constraints? Or do I have to implement myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no constraints on the Route Path itself, i.e. this definition:

```cs
[Route("/parents/{parentId}", HttpMethods.Delete)]
```

Will match every **DELETE** request that matches the route, i.e:

```
DELETE /parents/1
DELETE /parents/foo
```

You can apply routing constraints with a [Custom Route Rule](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#custom-rules), e.g:

```cs
[Route("/parents/{parentId}", HttpMethods.Delete, Matches = "**/{int}")]
```

Will apply the built-in `**/{int}` route rule to only match routes where the last segment is an integer, i.e:

```
DELETE /parents/1
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I have to stick with ServiceStack v4.5 for a while, and there is no `Matches` property on `[Route]`. Do you have any idea how I can implement that?

Comment: @DavidLiang Custom Route Rules was [added in v5.0 in 2017](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5_0_0#routes-with-custom-rules), you'll need to upgrade to a version beyond that for this feature, up to [v5.14 released early this year](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6#v5-14-releases-and-net-4-5-branches) which was the last release to support .NET v4.5.